# Find shortest route with waypoints using distance matrix

Tags: algorithm, google-maps

I want to get the shortest route between point A and B with X waypoints in between using google maps v3.

For this example lets say I want to calculate shortest route between A and B with C, D, E waypoints in between.

In order to do so I am using the distance matrix service to find the distance between [A-B, A-C, A-D], [B-C, B-D, B-E], [C-D, C-E], [D-E] with the results below:

> A) Address A [B: 4, C: 1.4, D: 1.4] Always beginning of route
>
> B) Address B [C: 3.8 ,D: 1.3, E: 3.1]
>
> C) Address C [D: 1.2, E: 3.1]
>
> D) Address D [E: 2.7]
>
> E) Address E - Always end of route
>
> Route 1: A + B + C + D + E = 4 + 3.8 + 1.2 + 2.7 = 11.7Kms
>
> Route 2: A + C + B + D + E = 1.4 + 3.8 + 1.3 + 2.7 = 9.2Kms
>
> Route 3: A + D + B + C + E = 1.4 + 1.3 + 3.8 + 3.1 = 9.6Kms
>
> Route: A + B + D + C + E = 4 + 1.3 + 1.2 + 3.1 = 9.6Kms
>
> Route 5: A + C + D + B + E =1.4 + 1.2 + 1.3 + 3.1 = 7Kms
>
> Route 6: A + D + C + B + E = 1.4 + 1.2 + 3.8 + 3.1 = 9.5 Kms

In this case the winner is Route 5 but I have three questions:

1. is this a suicide in terms of google maps billing with high volumes? Taking into account that routes will have a maximum of 12 addresses including both beginning and ending addresses.
2. is this a suicide in terms of javascript performance?
3. is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the question, you write: 'shortest route between A and B with C, D, E waypoints in between.' Did you mean between A and E with B, C, and D in between? And must there be an exact number of points in between? How about A-C-E?

Comment: - Did you mean between A and E with B, C, and D in between? yes, exactly as for second question the number of waypoints may change between users but those waypoints specified must be visited. i.e if A B C D E F are provided we must start on A and end on F and visit B C D E in whatever order makes up the shortest route. Not sure if I explained myself

Comment: I was going to suggest something about pruning the highest distances, but I realized that that might make it impossible to traverse the graph without serious consideration. There are (n-2)! x (n-2) x (n - 3) routes in total, so with n = 12, it is 331,272,000. So if JavaScript can handle that in an acceptable amount of time...

Comment: Have you looked at the DirectionsService with optimized waypoints?

Comment: Thanks you very much @geocodezip It worked that way. I was making It more complex than It is

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Keep lists of all distances (let us say, A --> F, with B, C, D, and E middle-points):

```
A: AB, AC, AD, AE
B: BC, BD, BE, BF
C: CB, CD, CE, CF
D: DB, DC, DE, DF
E: EB, EC, ED, EF
```

Let us say that we sort these according to the distances.

From A, choose the shortest distance (let's say it is AC).

From C, choose the shortest distance to another middle-point (CE?)

Repeat this and get something like A-C-E-B-D-F. Store this distance as d_min.

Go back and try another path. The first thing we can change is E-B, which we can change to E-D. Is A-C-E-D-B longer than A-C-E-B-D-F? If so, go further back and try A-C-B. If not, test A-C-E-D-B-F against d_min.

And so on - this will potentially save you some longer routes, and it *will* find the shortest one, although it may test all permutations. I don't think there exists much faster ways to do this however.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MinosIllyrien I finally used the Route service